# Apple Application Icons

Tags: iphone, macos, interface, icons

Does anyone have a good resource/pack for royalty free icons to be used in Mac Applications? (i.e. the "tack" button in iCal, etc.). I know there are quite a few out there for iOS..

Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are pretty good: http://glyphish.com/

Comment: thanks - i actually already have those but I didn't even think about using them for Mac. should work